# Remove characters from a character column in R based on values in another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame of team names and abbreviations. Currently, the team name column also contains the abbreviation. I'm trying to remove the abbreviation from the team name column to avoid repeating information.

Here's my current data frame:

| Team Abbr. | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| ARK | ArkansasARK |
| BSU | Boise StateBSU |
| DART | DartmouthDART |

My desired output is this:

| Team Abbr. | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| ARK | Arkansas |
| BSU | Boise State |
| DART | Dartmouth |

Thanks!

Comment: Am I correct in the following assumptions: 1) Each row has an abbreviation and a name, 2) you only want to remove that row's abbreviation from the name, 3) The abbreviation will always be unique and safe to remove (ie, here it's in all caps and will never appear legitimately in the name of the team. If an abbreviation could be `Da` for `DartmouthDa`, for example, then we'd need to be more careful)

Comment: I really need to use the abbreviations from the dataframe above and remove them from team names that exist in a different dataframe. 
1) Yes, every team name will have an abbreviation and a name
2) I only want to remove the abbreviation
3) Yes, the abbreviations will always be in all CAPS and unique

Answer (score 0):

We may use `str_remove` which is vectorized for both pattern and string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(TeamName = str_remove(TeamName, fixed(TeamAbbr)))
  TeamAbbr    TeamName
1      ARK    Arkansas
2      BSU Boise State
3     DART   Dartmouth
```

---

If we want to do this from a column in different dataset and the lengths are different, one option is to `paste` (`str_c`) the elements together with `|` (`OR`) as pattern

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(TeamName = str_remove(TeamName, str_c(TeamAbbr,
       collapse = "|")))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(TeamAbbr = c("ARK", "BSU", "DART"), 
TeamName = c("ArkansasARK", 
"Boise StateBSU", "DartmouthDART")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! For my own understanding, does this also work where the `Team Name` column also exists in another data frame? For example:

df2 %>%
     mutate(`Team Name` = str_remove(`Team Name`, df1$`Team Abbr.`))

Comment: @AndrewMcKinney As I said earlier, one of the requirement is that the number of rows should be the same as it is doing elementwise replacement

Comment: Is there a solution for when the rows in df2 are not the same length? Here's some additional context. df1 has a complete list of abbreviations and team names. df2 contains 25-30 team names (with the abbreviations included, like DartmouthDART), but the 25-30 teams change each time the data gets updated. 

Also, team names in df2 are guaranteed to exist in df1.

Comment: You may do this `df2 %>% mutate(TeamName = str_remove(TeamName, str_c(TeamAbbr, collapse = "|")))`

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution. Loop by rows with `apply` and replace the 1st column's value in the 2nd with the emp string.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
'Team Abbr.'    'Team Name'
ARK     ArkansasARK
BSU     'Boise StateBSU'
DART    DartmouthDART
", header = TRUE)
df1
#>   Team.Abbr.      Team.Name
#> 1        ARK    ArkansasARK
#> 2        BSU Boise StateBSU
#> 3       DART  DartmouthDART

df1$Team.Name <- apply(df1, 1, \(x) sub(x[1], "", x[2]))
df1
#>   Team.Abbr.   Team.Name
#> 1        ARK    Arkansas
#> 2        BSU Boise State
#> 3       DART   Dartmouth
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>